# Android/iOS unlimited Apps tied to a single website subscription

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-play, app-store

I have a website that provides a service that customers pay a monthly subscription fee. I have created apps for Android and iOS to connect to the subscribed account. With this subscription they can connect an unlimited number of users with android/iOS applications to the account.

If I release the App into the Market as free but customers need to register for a paid subscription for the main account on the website then will be seen as a breach of the Market T&Cs for the Play Store and the App Store?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine - some large companies do this, examples off the top of my head are: Rdio, Economist.

You can only purchase via their website, but by linking accounts you get full functionality.

The company gets to save on 30% fees, but the app is not allowed to provide any links to your purchase workflow on your website - otherwise that will violate the terms.

This is the same for both Android and iOS.